# Problem renaming a file in document library programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, event-handlers, feature-activation

I want to use a FeatureEventReceiver to rename Home.aspx -> Old_Home.aspx.  When i activate the feature rather than Home.aspx getting renamed it gets deleted/disappears (i.e. missing when i refresh sharepoint designer) from the library.  Here is the FeatureActivated....what be i doing wrong?

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPWeb curWeb = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
            SPSite curSite = curWeb.Site;
            SPWeb rootWeb = curSite.RootWeb;

            /* Rename Home.aspx to Old_Home.aspx */

            SPList list = rootWeb.Lists["Site Pages"];
            if (list != null)
            {
                foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                {
                    if (item["Name"].Equals("Home.aspx"))
                    {
                        item.File.CheckOut();
                        item["Name"] = "Old_Home.aspx";
                        item.Update();
                        item.File.CheckIn("file name has been changed");
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }            
        }
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this doesnt work when you have multiple language packs installed...

This Will help you :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2008/10/02/programmatically-rename-a-file-inside-a-sharepoint-document-library.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Could you be missing

```
item.File.Publish();
```

Also, as you debug, is there any exception thrown?
Any entry on the ULS or on the Event Viewer that could give you some clue of what's happening?